# Postive interval problem lower bound

Tags: algorithms, lower-bounds

I was trying to solve the question given below.

[image]

Algorithm :

Using divide and conquer technique, divide the input till we get a very small size array's ( let us say of size 2 ). Solve these small size array's in a brute force way. In the Merge phase it will take $\mathcal{O}(n)$ time to sum both arrays, if we get a positive sum then one contigious array will be sufficient to cover all positive numbers.

**Runtime :** $T(n)=2T(n/2)+\mathcal{O}(n)$

Which implies $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$ runtime Algorithm.

**Question:** How to prove that one can't solve the above problem in time better than $\mathcal{O}(n\log n)$?

Comment: Do you actually mean whether there is an algorithm runs better than $\mathcal O(n\log n)$?

Comment: @Apass.Jack  yes

Comment: @I_wil_break_wall, $T(n)=T(n/2)+\mathcal{O}(n)$ means $T(n)=\mathcal O(n)$. It looks like you missed a factor of 2, "$T(n)=2T(n/2)+\mathcal{O}(n)$".

Comment: I don't see why the algorithm you give works.. In the merge phase, you imply we either want to resolve the two halves independently or take the whole interval. But it might be possible the optimal solution uses an interval that overlaps with the midpoint and yet is not the whole segment.

Consider [1 -2 3 -3 -3 3 -2 1]. The optimal solution is [[1] -2 [3 -3 -3 3] -2 [1]].

Comment: @Elirsouag: `Check the maximum subset sum algorithm` [Maximum *subarray* problem/Kadane's algorithm](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_subarray_problem#Kadane's_algorithm)? `close enough` guess I don't see that.

Comment: I might have spoken too fast. There is no "obvious link", as I thought.

Comment: @TimonKnigge: `The optimal solution is [[1] -2 [3 -3 -3 3] -2 [1]]` I beg to differ: `called a positive interval if the sum is greater than zero` - not given for "the middle interval". Moreover, `[[1 -2 3] -3 -3 [3 -2 1]]` looks better.

Comment: I removed my answer : it was in fact wrong. What I proved is that if a merge could be made, the algorithm made it. However, it is not because a merge *can* be made that it has to be made. Example : `[1, -7, 7, -2, 1, -2, 1]`. The algorithm sees that you can merge the `7` towards the left, and it does, yielding solution `[[1, -7, 7], -2, [1], -2, [1]]`, and the optimal solution is `[[1], -7, [7, -2, 1, -2, 1]]`

Comment: I would also add that this exercise is in an [algorithm textbook](http://jeffe.cs.illinois.edu/teaching/algorithms/), in the **greedy algorithms** section.

Comment: @JohnL. Can we solve above problem with greedy approach? I have an algorithm, it seems not working.

Comment: @ART Can you please ask a new question and present your algorithm?

Comment: There is a greedy algorithm that runs in $O(n)$ time.